# How to invoke SendKeys() to the input element through Selenium and C#

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Basically, I want to Send Keys to an input element. I tried using `SendKeys()` method but it doesn't send the value I used instead it uses the previous value attribute of the input box. Moreover, using `SendKeys()` or using `ExecuteScript()` methods doesn't change the value attribute of the input element. Below are the code pieces I have tried and didn't work so far :

```
// Wait for zipcode input box
Utilities.WaitUntilElementIsPresent(driver, By.CssSelector("input#fad-dealer-searchbar-search-textbox"));
// click to go to the us site
var zipcodeInput = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input#fad-dealer-searchbar-search-textbox"));
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;

zipcodeInput.Clear();
zipcodeInput.Click();
//js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '11361')", zipcodeInput);
//js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('fad-dealer-searchbar-search-textbox').setAttribute('value', " + zipcode + ")");
//js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('fad-dealer-searchbar-search-textbox').value=11361");
//js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('fad-dealer-searchbar-search-textbox').innerHTML = 11361;");
zipcodeInput.SendKeys(zipcode);
zipcodeInput.Submit();
zipcodeInput.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
```

Here is the input element that i need to enter the text to :

```
<div class="sdp-form-text-box-text-box-container search-textbox">      
  <input type="number" autocomplete="off" value="00002" data-validation-state="success" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" class="sdp-form-text-box-text-box gcss-button-align-left" id="fad-dealer-searchbar-search-textbox" maxlength="5" name="searchTextBoxValue" pattern="\d*" placeholder="Enter ZIP Code" required="" role="search">                                           
</div>
```

Here is the site I'm crawling if you guys need to check it [Chrysler](https://www.chrysler.com/find-dealer.html). 
I hope I have explained my issue properly. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: After testing the same code on different sites found out that it's an issue that occurs when web crawling through the Chrysler site. However, I'm still looking for a way to achieve this task.

Answer (score 2):

In the function "WaitUntilElementIsPresent" you need to check the expected conditions applied on webdriver. Following is the similar code. You can use "ElementIsVisible" or "ElementToBeClickable".

```
public static IWebElement WaitUntilElementIsPresent(this IWebDriver driver,By elementLocator, int timeout = 10)
    {
        try
        {
            var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout));
            return wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(elementLocator));
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Element with locator: '" + elementLocator + "' was not found.");
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this will only throw the exception message. See the comments under @DebanjanB answer

Answer (score 1):

To invoke `SendKeys()` you need to induce *WebDriverWait* in conjunction with [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm) as [ElementToBeClickable](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_ElementToBeClickable.htm) and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  var zipcodeInput = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("label.gcss-sr-only[for^='change-zip__input-field-']")));
  zipcodeInput.Click();
  zipcodeInput.Clear();
  zipcodeInput.SendKeys(zipcode);
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  var zipcodeInput = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//label[@class='gcss-sr-only' and starts-with(@for, 'change-zip__input-field-')]")));
  zipcodeInput.Click();
  zipcodeInput.Clear();
  zipcodeInput.SendKeys(zipcode);
  ```

**Note**:

- Ensure that *zipcode* consists of numbers only.
- Ensure that *zipcode* maximum length is **5** digits only.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it's not working because it throws `OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException: 'Timed out after 20 seconds'
`. However, the `zipcodeInput.Clear();` and  `zipcodeInput.Click();` methods worked before  (forgot to mention that). Then again this condition should not fail because `Clear()` and `Click()` methods worked on it.

Comment: Still it throws the `WebDriverTimeoutException` from `WebDriverWait` so it won't reach the below code.

Comment: @LordDraagon Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status

Comment: Still the same exception is thrown. However, I used this `         js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('fad-dealer-searchbar-search-textbox').children[0].children[1].children[0].value = "+ zipcode +"");` and traversed to select the input box and set the value. Now it changes the value but when i invoke the enter key it changes back to `00002`